# Interpreting regression model when parameter significance changes as two dummy variable levels are switched

Tags: regression, interaction

I have seen this question asked before, but I am having difficulty applying the answers I've seen to my specific data set. I apologize if this is duplicated.

I have some animal data where rats were given two separate conditions - Intermittent and Continuous. I am using R to determine whether the rate of their behavior interacts with the condition to predict behavioral test results. So my model is assessing:

Expected(Test) = Condition + Rate + Condition * Rate

R-Code:

```
regData %>%
  mutate(Condition = case_when(Condition == "Int" ~ 0,
                                 Condition == "Cont" ~ 1)) -> regData2

reg <- lm(test ~ Condition*Rate, data = regData2)
```

When I change the values of the dummy variables (i.e. Int is now '1' instead of '0') the Rate parameter becomes significant, however, when Continuous is coded as '1' Rate is non-significant.  When I am calculating individual regression models for each condition, I am not sure whether to include rate as a parameter since it may or may not be significantly related to 'test' results. What would you suggest? In addition, one of the output's intercepts was not determined to be significant, either. Does that effect the regression model?

I will include both R outputs for visual reference:

```
# Continuous is 1


Call:
lm(formula = test ~ Condition * Rate, data = regData2)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-96.34 -44.76 -34.22  49.58 118.53 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)      -9.687    117.413  -0.083   0.9363  
Condition      -840.046    326.161  -2.576   0.0328 *
Rate            291.060    145.509   2.000   0.0805 .
Condition:Rate 4258.031   1330.359   3.201   0.0126 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 84.4 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6679,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5433 
F-statistic: 5.363 on 3 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.02564
```

```
# Continuous is 0


Call:
lm(formula = test ~ Condition * Rate, data = regData2)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-96.34 -44.76 -34.22  49.58 118.53 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)       -849.7      304.3  -2.792  0.02347 * 
Condition          840.0      326.2   2.576  0.03284 * 
Rate              4549.1     1322.4   3.440  0.00882 **
Condition:Rate   -4258.0     1330.4  -3.201  0.01260 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 84.4 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6679,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5433 
F-statistic: 5.363 on 3 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.02564
```

Thank you very much - this community is so helpful.